# How to move partition with Users to a new SATA controller?

Tags: windows-7, boot, backup, raid, sata

Our current situation: X79 chipset. Windows 7 installed on SATA SSD running on Marvell controller. C:\Users contains just Public and computer-name folders, all the other users are created in E:\Users. That partition is on two HDD's running on an Intel RAID controller. (The motherboard has got two SATA/RAID onboard controllers.)

The goal is: Without reinstallation, I want to move SSD to a standard SATA controller. Then I want to get rid of RAID1, and move one HDD to the same internal Intel SATA controller and the current E:\Users move to that new place. I want it to stay as E:\users, but I need to reinstall the HDD to let it work in SATA mode without RAID.

So I face several problems. I am sure all are solvable with free software utilities, but I don't know how exactly to do it. I can see the particular problems:

1. I have got all users at E:\Users. When I turn off that E:\ disk, I won't be able to login to Windows. I need at least one admin account to be placed back at C:\users.
2. The current C: runs on standard 120 GB SSD, but it is connected to a Marvell SATA/RAID controller. I am affraid the Windows won't let me put it to Intel SATA controller due to hardware/licence check, and I won't be able to use standard W7 recovery disk either, because there probably isn't marvel SATA/RAID driver on it. I haven't tried anything yet, because I am affraid I can end up with computer not working at all. (I want to move it to a standard ICH10 Intel SATA controller to let us have no problems in future with it. I think it is not very safe when we use any nonstandard hardware to boot the computer.)
3. I need to somehow backup current E:\ disk and restore it to a new E:. I hope this will be the easy part (as long as the admin account will reside on C:). The E: RAID array is very large, but it is almost empty (less than 100 GB of data.) So I can make the partition smaller so it can easily fit to a single SATA HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, it all went quite easily, quickly a smoothly. And no special software was needed.

1. I simply set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` to C:\users. Then I created a new admin user account, and then I set that registry key back to E:\Users.
2. I opened IBM RAID manager in Windows 7, and deleted RAID partition.
3. I turned off the computer, and swapped the SATA cables. (SSD to Intel SATA3 controller, HDD's to Marvell SATA3 controller.)
4. I unplugged SATA cables from HDD's, turned on the computer, changed BIOS SATA mode from RAID to AHCI.
5. I booted to Windows 7, plugged the SATA cables to HDD's. One of them appeared as E: and everything works fine. :-)
6. I used diskpart command line utility to change unique ID of the other disk of the former RAID1 array. Then deleted and recreated NTFS partition on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new user with admin rights
2. Logon to that account
3. In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` find your current admin account and chage `ProfileImagePath` to `c:\users\youradmin` and move his home folder to `c:\users\`
4. Restart PC and logon as that current admin
5. Now you can create new E: partition and move other accounts there

Comment: Is it possible to "move" all files with all current flags and ACL? I mean other way than backup-restore partition. I mean does some command line utility copy everything with access rights, including possible existing file encryption?